# ubuntu 16.04 forgot password

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I use vmware ubuntu 16.04 linux. Since i had not used the system for sometime i had forgotten the password. I have only 2 users of which one is a guest and the other is "aname". Since i was not able to remember the password i tried as suggested in https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-lost-root-password-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux but i didnt even had a root user. I used aname user only. But the link suggested to change root password only, i tried doing a su or sudo aname it didnt work. Kindly suggest a way to change my aname account password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are logged as root, execute this command to change password of user `aname`:

```
passwd aname
```

*([`passwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html) command defaults to edit password of current user, but also accepts a user name as optional parameter to select which password to change)*

Comment: what if we can not log on as root / sudo ..